# serving static files with nginx on diffent machine and gunicorn on a diffrent one for a django production

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx, gunicorn

Am currently having nginx and gunicorn on same server but want to have them on different servers I tried having the setup as followed.Postgres on a different machine(server1) which is then connected to gunicorn on server2.Server2 has an external hard which gunicon save and uplouds file to.Gunicon is on a local network and can't be accessed from outside.I have a symbolic link from my app to the external hard drive.on server3 I have nginx which can be accessed from outside which is proxy to nginx on server2 .I do not want gunicon to server static files so I did a sshfs link to mount point on server too and then ngix now server static content directly. this all works fine but then I notice from time to time the sshfs connection always cut which is not good in production. Please can any one advice me the right way to do this in a production environment.Here is a off hand of my configuration.

Server2

```
# mount /dev/sde1 /home/me/HD
$ mkdir -p /home/me/HD/currentapp/static && mkdir -p /home/me/HD/currentapp/media
$ ln -s /home/me/HD/currentapp/media  /allmyapps/currentapp/currentapp/media
$ ln -s /home/me/HDcurrentapp/static  /allmyapps/currentapp/currentapp/static
```

Server3

```
$ mkdir -p /home/me/HD/currentapp/
# sshfs -p(port number here) me@Server2:/home/me/HD /home/me/HD -o uid=1000 -o gid=33 -o allow_other
```

server3 nginx

```
upstream my_server {
server server2:port fail_timeout=0;
}

location /static/ {
alias /home/me/HD/currentapp/static/;
}
location /media/ {
alias /home/me/HD/currentapp/media/;
}

location / {
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_redirect off;
if (!-f $request_filename) {
proxy_pass http://my_server;
break;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please can any one advice me the right way to do this in a production
>   environment.

Use a network attached storage (NAS) device that is mounted on both machines. This is how you would do it the *right way* in production.

You could do all sorts of other workarounds - like rsync, nfs, etc. however **the most reliable way** to have this working is with a proper NAS.